# Can't access Outlook.com from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dns, email, browser

I did a clean install of of Ubuntu few weeks ago (was working on Windows10). I am facing this totally frustrating problem. I cannot access my hotmail/outlook account. 
I get to the site, i enter my credentials, i am passing the security test and then nothing...just a blank page. 
[Just like that!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyNma.jpg)

What i get on Inspect is just a blank html body, and on console there is also nothing.

Searching around i saw it has something to do with DNS. I install NSCD, restarted the service, even tried to use google's DNS server but setting them as default through my router, but nothing!

Comment: What makes you think it has something to do with DNS? Have you tried another browser (e.g. Chromium)?

Comment: I am not saying that that's the problem...it is just another guess...I tried Chrome, Chromium, Firefox even IE with wine for crying out loud...nothin...I even did a reinstall of the OS with another copy but still nothing..on the other hand my laptop which is running WindowsOS is connecting fine

Comment: Can you go on "Inspect" and to the networking tab to see which resources it's trying to load?

Comment: Its all blank as I seem to recall...I will check it once again once I am back. Thanks for help!

Comment: When it's blank, try a reload with F5, it should at least show you one 404 error or something.

Comment: Thats the network tab http://i.imgur.com/j2bhtp3.jpg and after lots of time we have this result http://i.imgur.com/AbR56L7.jpg

Comment: Judging from that owa/ pending document at the bottom, the site is trying to load the "Outlook Web App". It might just simply not work on non-Windows systems, but further research can't do any harm.

Comment: But works fine on other Linux system I work on...

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I can't help you, I'm not using an Outlook account, so I can't test this myself.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem recently, and it had to do with the DNS indeed. The following solved the problem for me:

- Right click on the network manager icon of the task bar.
- Go to "Edit Connections"
- Select the active network connection and click "edit"
- Go to the "IPv4 Settings" tab
- Fill in the field "additional DNS servers"
- Re-load the connection for the settings to apply.

Now for free DNS servers you can just search the web and find a lot... I initially used the google one which is 8.8.8.8. Now I see that just by entering the IP of my router does the job just as well.

I hope this helps